# Connection String: Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

> ```
>  Server Error in '/' Application.
>
>     The system cannot find the file specified
>
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> ```
>
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> ```
>     Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
>
>     Source Error: 
>
>     An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location
> ```
>
> of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace
>   below.

Connection String

```
<add name="DashboardManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ManagementEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.ManagementEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.ManagementEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Database\abc.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DatabaseModel" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Database\abc.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Stack Trace

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +6568558    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6595000
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +219
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6597350
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6597891
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +6601145
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +103
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +1079
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   +6605639    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +233
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +278    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +207
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +438
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +15
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +263
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +436
>
> [EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +701
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean
>   shouldMonitorTransactions) +170
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +70
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>   +239    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +263
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +368
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   +11    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +50    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +536
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
>   Dashboard.Models.UserRepository.Get(String id) +132
>   Dashboard.Account.Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) +134
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +155
>   System.Web.UI.d__14.MoveNext() +8108

**If someone could get me the correct connection string and solution for this i'd be very thankful.**

Comment: is this working before?

Comment: @FrancisSaul i changed the server, now its not working.

Comment: what's the version of your sql server? You've change the server ? a different hardware or just the code in webconfig?? well if you're using sql 2008 and a webconfig try this 

  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQL2008;database=nameOfUrDB; User=sa;Password=YourPW" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     </connectionStrings>

Comment: Did you turn on SQL service in SQL management studio?

Comment: There is problem with your ConnectionString Your Datasource name or username or password name must be wrong. try this ".\SQL2008" use "."  and provide your correct user name and password.

Comment: Is it from a remote server? If it is, make sure the you can access it through the firewall

Comment: @FrancisSaul I'm using same SQL Version 2014 and using windows auth. MDF file needs auth?

Comment: @User2012384 No. Do i need to for MDF file?

Comment: @RaviKanth I'm using Windows Auth.

Comment: Then here is the problem, you turn on the service first

Comment: try to create a new/fresh connection using MDF files just to see if your new server/sql is working fine.